# MethodChannel to mock OpenFile package in flutter for ResultType.noAppToOpen in test

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I am trying to mock the package of OpenFile in Flutter for `ResultType.noAppToOpen` in the test
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRYiV.png)

So I did the method channel below.

```
const MethodChannel('open_file').setMockMethodCallHandler(methodCall) { return OpenResult(message: 'No APP found to open this file.' , type: ResultType.noAppToOpen);
```

But I am unable to have the desired return of `ResultType.noAppToOpen` in my test as it is returning me `ResultType.error` instead.
Am I doing the methodChannel wrongly for this since there is filePath inside `OpenFile.open(filePath)` ? Or is the methodChannel not working for this. Thank you.